# Winter hat showing up in math expressions

Tags: bug, winter-bash, mathjax

Noticed a small bug in Mathematics Stack Exchange, though perhaps it might exist anywhere using MathJax. The winter hat (in this case, "Gimme Space") shows up inside the rendered expressions. I do not know why it is in that expression specifically. The post shown below is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092022/cauchy-hadamard-formula-proof).

> [image]

Comment: That's a bug in the cache I guess